Postgresql: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown
The following query works:
select
  t.oid,
  t.typname,
  case t.typcategory
    when 'C' then json_object('{}')
    when 'E' then (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(enumlabel::text)) FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = t.oid)
  end as definition
from pg_type t
where t.typcategory IN ('C', 'E');

But the next fails with the error:

could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown

select
  t.oid,
  t.typname,
  case t.typcategory
    when 'C' then json_object('{}')
    when 'E' then (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(enumlabel::text)) FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = t.oid)
    when 'S' then to_json('string')
  end as definition
from pg_type t
where t.typcategory IN ('C', 'E', 'S');

I do not understand why.

json_object returns json
array_to_json returns json
to_json returns json

What is the problem?

The problem is the to_json('string').
String literals like 'string' initially have the internal type unknown, and the actual data type is derived from context according to the type conversion rules for functions.
Now the problem is that to_json() has anyelement as input data type, which means that you can supply arguments of an arbitrary data type. That confounds the type resolution rules: the argument is of undefined type, and anyelement doesn't give PostgreSQL any context to resolve the actual data type. So it just gives up in confusion.
You can solve the problem by explicitly specifying the data type:
to_json(TEXT 'string')


But is there a chance that to_json will ever return anything else but json?

No, the problem is the argument. And to_json will behave differently, depending on the input data type. Compare SELECT to_json(INTEGER '1'), to_json(TEXT '1').

But how can the argument matter if the result type is always json whatever argument you pass to to_json?

Because the JSON might be different each time, see my previous comment.

Do you want to say that the type json does not exist in PostgreSQL, because only "json-string" and "json-number" actually exist?

No, both are type json. But a JSON string looks different from a JSON number.

And how about pretty and ugly looking strings?

Huh? And why do you ask these questions? Was my answer unclear?

Yes I think it makes no sense. I have never heard about types having a "look". In other languages JSON is typically a runtime type. This means a variable of the type JSON may contain a string or a number. But a variable of the type JSON containing a string has the same type as a variable of the type JSON containing a number, because both are JSON. If I have a table with a column of the type JSON, it also does not matter if the column contains rows of the type JSON containing a string or rows of the type JSON containing a number, because both are JSON.

I guess you should read the JSON specification. I get the feeling that this discussion is leading nowhere and is just an expression of your unhappiness with the way PostgreSQL works. Let's stop here.
